# Objective-C preprocessor available?

Tags: c, objective-c, compiler-construction

Does anyone know if the source code for Objective-C is still available from when it was just a pre-processor? Would be curious to see how it was implemented back then.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Clang LLVM rewriter](http://clang.llvm.org/) (rewriter is documented below there) can rewrite Objective-C into C (and is being used by some to compile Objective-C for the Xbox and Windows).

Some discussion here:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/32019

Answer (score 2):

The only source-available implementation of Objective-C is GCC. The GCC archive at ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc contains versions back to 1.42, while ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/gcc has some versions slightly older than that. The earliest implementations within GCC were, I believe, preprocessors, so that's probably your best bet.